# How do I add a destroy method in jQuery CoolInput?

Tags: jquery, destroy

I am looking at: [CoolInput](http://www.alexweber.com.br/jquery/coolinput/?dontclear=vbfg), but I need a destroy method.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
$('#manualhint2').coolinput('foobar');
```

but I also need a method like:

```
$('#manualhint2').coolinput(destroy);
```

or something like that, because there are times when I need to disable CoolInput.

Can somebody please help me?
Or, you can also recommend another jquery hint library that has a destroy method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$('#manualhint2').coolinput('');
```

?

Comment: that makes sense! why didn't i think of it? >_<

Comment: Glad it worked. Sometimes you just stare at something and completely miss the obvious. I believe they call it "not seeing the wood for the trees". I know this from personal experience.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit explore in CoolInput code, I got this:

```
$(selector).each(function () {
  EmptyThisCoolInput($(this));
});

function EmptyThisCoolInput(o) {
  try {
    if (o.val() == o.attr(coolInputAttribute) && o.hasClass(coolinputBlurClass))
      o.val("").removeClass(coolinputBlurClass);
  } catch (e) { }
}
```

I separated `EmptyThisCoolInput` because I call this somewhere else. you can safely use this syntax:

```
$(selector).each(function () {
  try {
    if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr(coolInputAttribute) && $(this).hasClass(coolinputBlurClass))
      $(this).val("").removeClass(coolinputBlurClass);
  } catch (e) { }
});
```